# Node.js - Converting a SQL query into Knex.js

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have a SQL query (Postgres) containing several `join`s that I'm having trouble converting into a single Knex.js statement. Here's the SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    User.id, User.name, User.email,
    Role.name AS r_name,
    UserPofile.id AS p_id, UserPofile.date_of_birth AS p_dob,
    AuthToken.id AS at_id, AuthToken.token AS at_token, AuthToken.platform AS at_platform
FROM public."user" User
    LEFT JOIN public."user_role" UserRole ON User.id = UserRole.user_id
    LEFT JOIN public."role" Role ON UserRole.role_id = Role.id
    LEFT JOIN public."application" Application ON UserProfile.app_id = Application.id
    LEFT JOIN public."user_profile" UserProfile ON User.id = UserProfile.user_id
    LEFT JOIN public."auth_token" AuthToken ON User.id = AuthToken.user_id
WHERE 
    User.email LIKE 'some@email.com' AND
    Application.name LIKE 'awesome-application' AND
    AuthToken.platform LIKE 'mobile';
```

Here's my Knex.js code:

```
    return knex('user').where({ email:'some@email.com' })
    .select([
        'user.id', 'user.name', 'user.email' // User
        'role.name AS rName' // Roles
        'user_profile.id AS pId', 'user_profile.date_of_birth AS pDob' // UserProfiles
        'auth_token.id AS atId' 'auth_token.platform AS atPlatform', 'auth_token.token AS atToken' // AuthTokens
    ])
    .leftJoin('user_profile', 'user_profile.user_id', 'user.id')
    .leftJoin('user_role', 'user_role.user_id', 'user.id')
    .leftJoin('role', 'role.id', 'user_role.role_id')
    .leftJoin('auth_token', 'auth_token.user_id', 'user.id')
    .then(users => {

        users = users.filter(user => { 
            return user.pApp_id === appId && user.atApp_id === appId && user.atPlatform === platform; 
        });
        return users;
    });
```

This produces the same result that the SQL query does, but the problem is that I have to filter the returned users in the `.then()` clause of the Knex call because I don't know how to add `WHERE` conditions for the `Application.name` and `AuthToken.platform`.

**Question:**

Can someone please help me figure out how to structure my Knex code's `.where()` clause to have it be equivalent to the SQL query?

**Notes:**

- I don't know how to `console.log` the SQL queries that Knex produces, therefore I'm not entirely sure that my current Knex code will produce the SQL query above it (minus the correct `WHERE` clause). I have checked though that it does in fact return the same results, by running the query in PgAdmin and `console.log()`ing the `users` returned in from the Knex function.
- I haven't included the `CREATE TABLE` / Knex migrations that defined the tables and columns used in this question, because to me it didn't feel necessary, and I don't want to make an already long question even longer. But if you need to see it, please don't hesitate to let me know. I'll gladly include it.

Comment: Can you just make it a procedure and pass an input? Seems like a better process.

Comment: @Jacob_H That sounds intriguing. Do you maybe have some resources I can look at to get me started?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To debug you can use `.toSQL()` to debug your knex queries [documentation](https://knexjs.org/#2832).
Also, nice [cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/knex) 

As hot fix solution you can use [`.raw()`](https://knexjs.org/#Schema-raw) and paste your SQL code there.

About `WHERE` conditions, you can just chain them in the end of your knex query.
Something like this:

```
return knex('user')
  .select('user.id', 'user.name', 'user.email', 
    'role.name AS rName'
    'user_profile.id AS pId', 'user_profile.date_of_birth AS pDob', 
    'auth_token.id AS atId' 'auth_token.platform AS atPlatform', 'auth_token.token AS atToken'
   )
  .leftJoin('user_profile', 'user_profile.user_id', 'user.id')
  .leftJoin('user_role', 'user_role.user_id', 'user.id')
  .leftJoin('role', 'role.id', 'user_role.role_id')
  .leftJoin('auth_token', 'auth_token.user_id', 'user.id') 
  .where('user.email', 'like', '%some@email.com%')
  .andWhere('application.name', 'like' '%awesome-application%')

//...etc
```

Comment: Hey! Adding more `.where()` clauses to the query ended up working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Simplest solution is use `.whereRaw()`:

[knex whereRaw](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereRaw)

#### Example:

```
.leftJoin('auth_token', 'auth_token.user_id', 'user.id')
.whereRaw('User.email LIKE ?', `${your_param_here}`)
.andWhereRaw('AuthToken.platform LIKE ?', `${your_param_here}`)
```